# Setting a file's "Last modified Date" | Touch a file (Noob-request)

Tags: vbscript

I need some quick support for a small code-snippet.
I want to "touch" a file or lets say change the "Last modified Date".

I have the following code-snippet:

```
Touch "C:\temp\VBS", "test.txt", "1/01/2006 11:00:00 PM"

Function Touch(strDir, strFileName, DateTime)

Dim objShell, objFolder

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(strDir)
objFolder.Items.Item(strFileName).ModifyDate = DateTime

End Function
```

It works, but I don't want to pass the folder and the file separately to the function. ("C:\temp\VBS" and "test.txt")
I want to pass a FQDN or "full name". ("C:\temp\VBS\test.txt")

All samples I found via Google use this split-tech and I am not able to write VB on my own ...

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The split is obviously motivated by the different arguments to .NameSpace and .Item. Given a full file spec, you can use the .GetParentFolderName and .GetFileName methods of the FileSystemObject:

```
Option Explicit

Dim goFS   : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim sFSpec : sFSpec = WScript.ScriptFullName
WScript.Echo "Path", goFS.GetParentFolderName(sFSpec)
WScript.Echo "Name", goFS.GetFileName(sFSpec)
```

output:

```
e:\work\proj\soa\42225862
cscript 42254081.vbs
Path e:\work\proj\soa\42225862
Name 42254081.vbs
```

Comment: I think I got it working based on your answer. Thank you!