# Use FileSystemObject to rewrite image file to directory with updated Modified Date?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

The `FileSystemObject` command `CopyFile` will take any file and make a copy of it, but it leaves the modified date intact. Is there a way to open an existing image (JPG, PNG, etc.) file and "write" it to the directory instead (two-step process?) that would cause the modified date to change? I know `FileSystemObject` can do this with text files, but not sure if there is a way to do it with a JPG or PNG.

Comment: You may do that using `ADODB.Stream` to read and write in binary mode. Also `aspjpeg` is a very easy use component to work with images in classic asp

Comment: Yes, works great, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

1. Copy your file with `FileSystemObject.CopyFile`
2. "Touch" the copied file with the function provided in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254081) question:

   ```
   Sub touch(strDir, strFileName, DateTime)
       Dim objShell, objFolder
       Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
       Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(strDir)
       objFolder.Items.Item(strFileName).ModifyDate = DateTime
   End Sub
   ```

... Pass the current date to `touch()`:

```
touch strDir, strFileName, Now
```